# Equivalent code to GCHandle.Alloc() in Java?

Tags: java, memory, jna

I'm working on wrapping a C DLL library to Java using JNA. The library has provided a C# wrapper. In the constructor of C# wrapper, a object is created and the memory of the object is pinned by

```
this.m_object = _CreateObject();
this.m_objectGCH = GCHandle.Alloc(this.m_object, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

m_object is an integer pointing to the created object, and the memory of the object is pinned by GCHandle.Alloc(). I can create a object and get the pointer to the object by JNA. However, I have no idea to pin the object memory in Java.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in java.  If you give more context (i.e. how/why are you trying to use the object w.r.t. JNA), then we may be able to suggest a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's GC has no awareness of the native memory allocated for your object.  If you are responsible for deleting the memory at some future point, you must do so explicitly in your Java code by calling whatever "free" method is recommended by your object allocation.

If you need to ensure that Java does not GC a given *Java* object, then you need to ensure there is a reference to it until you no longer need it (the easiest way to do so is by storing it in a static (class) variable).